# How to remove all special characters from the character string that comes as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, web, logic

I'm practicing Javascript logic exercises to improve in this language and prepare for future interviews and I find myself stuck on something that may seem basic, but I can't find the way around it, I don't know if someone could explain to me how to solve this problem.

The statement says that: The purpose of the FormatString function is to remove all special characters from the character string that comes as a parameter. Only the 26 letters of the English alphabet, numbers 0-9, spaces, and hyphens are allowed.

The program is as follows:

```
function FormatString(sentence) {
let result = []; 

sentence = sentence.toUpperCase(); 

let i = 0; 
let j = 0;

while (i < sentence.lenght){
    if(
        (sentence.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && sentence.charCodeAt(i) <=90) || (sentence.charCodeAt(i) >= 48 && sentence.charCodeAt(j) <= 57) || sentence.charCodeAt(i) == 32 ||
        sentence.charCodeAt(i) == 45
    ) {
        sentence[j] = result[i];
        j+=1;
    }
    i+=1;
}
return result.join(""); 
}
```

There are supposed to be errors in the exercise, but I can't identify them, I would like to make the code work, sorry if it's something very basic, but I'm still learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest (and most elegant) method to accomplish what you need.  Match the items and joined the matched array into a string:

```
function FormatString(sentence) {
    return sentence.match(/[a-z]|[0-9]|-|\s/gi).join('')
}
```

To Test:

```
console.log(FormatString('%this is 1212-33 QB)_'))
```

Comment: It doesn't work with French accents, like é, ç, à

Comment: @ThomasG2201 LOL.. it is funny comment! but thankfully requirement for English alphabet only

Comment: True lmao, however the presented solution doesn't take into account all scenarios, it's a limited answer, it's not global... why should we limit ourselves, as it is for an interview, doing better isn't better? you see what I mean?

Comment: Sorry i downvoted because it was missing the accents, but actually it was correct as the person wants english alphabet. Can't undo it before 15 minutes unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled `length` and its causing the output you're getting. And if you want to continue the approach in the example, you have to implement all the other character codes also.

A shorter way would be:

```js
const formatString = (sentence) => sentence.replace(/[^a-z\d\s\-]+/igm, '');
```

Comment: There is no way to write every single one of the excluded characters this way. Use `^` as presented in my solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace()` method from String and regular expression.

Basically, you want to remove everything that is **not** a-zA-Z0-9 -, so:

```js
const formatString = (sentence) => sentence.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]*/g, '');
```

More info on the official documentation of [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

For `replace` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: That is actually working, see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4qcxej5/)

Comment: LMAO, you missed the space. And why the underscore?

Comment: Sorry, still discovering the word "hyphens" for the french dude i am, let me fix this.

Comment: Bro, why literally the space character, why not the `\s`?

Comment: We could, yeah, we could also use \d, i didn't think about it

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know if it is part of your exercise or not but you typed
sentence.lenght, it is *length*

second: your code is actually uppercasing the sentence so it would return uppered sentence

you could add

```
(sentence.charCodeAt(i) >= 97 && sentence.charCodeAt(i) <= 122)
```

to check for "a-z" letters, don't forget to remove sentence.toUpperCase()